# Implement a function using sizeof

Tags: c

I am new in C programming and using a specific library. I need to use this function:

```
le_result_t le_ecall_ExportMsd ( le_ecall_CallRef_t     ecallRef,
                                 uint8_t *              msdPtr,
                                 size_t *               msdNumElementsPtr 
                                )
```

Where the parameters:

```
[in] ecallRef                   eCall reference
[out] msdPtr                    the encoded MSD
[in,out] msdNumElementsPtr
```

In order to get que encoded MSD I developed this code (a little bit simplified):

```
static le_ecall_CallRef_t    LastTestECallRef = NULL;
uint8_t msd[] = NULL;

void StarteCall (void)
{
    le_ecall_ExportMsd(LastTestECallRef, msd, sizeof(msd));
}
```

Sizeof is returning size_t and I need size_t * so I am getting the following error:

```
expected 'size_t *' but argument is of type 'unsigned int'
```

I would be gratefull if somebody could help me.

Comment: I don't think the error message could be any clearer. Ok, it could have said `expected 'size_t *' but argument is of type 'size_t' `, but even without, I find it quite telling.

Comment: "Sizeof is returning size_t and I need size_t *" - yes, that's the problem. What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass a pointer for the last parameter like so:

```
size_t nsize = sizeof(msd);
le_ecall_ExportMsd(LastTestECallRef, msd, &nsize);
```

The reason is because the function definition requires `size_t *msdNumElementsPtr` which is a pointer instead of `size_t msdNumElementsPtr`.

Comment: Thank you very much it works and I understand it